# How to see the type of variable within Android Studio IDE

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

How to see the type of variable in Android Studio when using Kotlin without type annotations.

Currently I'm trying to see it by giving the variable a type I know is incorrect and the IDE informs me with an error about the type it expected.

```
val variable = dont().know().type().ofThis()
```

To give example, I can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to see the signature of a function, is there a similar way to see the inferred type of a variable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can enable `Parameter name hints` for that

[image: Example of type hints]

To do so, go to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `General` -> `Appearance` and check the `Show parameter name hints`. Be sure to click `configure` button and at the `Options` panel, check the required options, including `show local variable type hints`:

[image: Enable type hints]
[image: Type hints configuration]

Answer (score 8):

There is a menu item in the View menu: "Type Info"

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in Android Studio Win 3.5.3

Answer (score 4):

Hakan Karaduman, thank you for the question!

I see that you found the correct answer, however, the Android Studio IDE is changed its `Settings` menu. Therefore, I decided to provide an updated location for the options that you requested.

In Android Studio 2021.1.1 Patch 1 the required list of options is located `File` > `Settings` > `Editor` > `Inlay Hints` > `Kotlin`. That location consists of the following groups:

- Parameter hints:

> .. [v] Show parameter hints
> ...... Exclude list..

- Types:

> .. [v] Show hints for: 
> ...... [v] Property types 
> ...... [v] Local variable types
> ...... [v] Function return types
> ...... [v] Function parameter types

- Lambdas:

> .. [v] Show hints for: 
> ...... [v] Return expressions
> ...... [v] Implicit receivers and parameters

**Upd #01** for `Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2`

`File` > `Settings` > `Editor` > `Inlay Hints`

- `Types` > `Kotlin`:

> .. [v] Property types
> .. [v] Local variable types
> .. [v] Function return types
> .. [v] Function parameter types

- `Values` > `Kotlin`:

> .. [v] Ranges

- `Lambdas` > `Kotlin`:

> .. [v] Return expressions
> .. [v] Implicit receivers and parameters